# Received QAM symbol demodulation

Tags: signal, communication, digital-communications, matlab, modulation

We're using 64QAM with unit average power and gray encoding.

The modulated representation corresponding to symbols :

> 1 => -0.923 + 0.659i
>
> 2 => -0.923 + 0.132i
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 45 => 0.659 -
> 0.659i
>
> .
> .

The received symbols can be found as \$\mathbf{s}_{\text{rx}}= \mathbf{H} \cdot \mathbf{s}_{\text{tx}}\$;

My question rises here, the received symbols are:

> -8.005 e-05 + 5.717 e-05i 
> -8.005e-05 + 1.143e-05i 
> 5.717e-05 - 5.717e-05i

How can I demodulate them ?

Using qamdemod with unit average power results high errors since it requires higher amplitude symbols as in given above (modulated symbols)

```
demodulated_symbols = qamdemod(rx_symbols, M, "UnitAveragePower", true);
```

instead I tried :

```
rx_symbols = rx_symbols ./mean(abs(rx_symbols ));
```

This operation amplified average power to be 1 but if there are low amount of symbols to take mean, it becomes biased and again results errors.
For example, this normalization resulted 1.8% symbol error rate for 30 symbols received but 30% symbol error rate for 3 symbols received.

**Real Question :**

**What is the proper way to demodulate received low power signal ?**

in MATLAB forums, they do not change signal power, instead they change noise power to adjust SNR, but I need to change signal power while keeping thermal noise constant (as in real life)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This operation amplified average power to be 1 but if there are low amount of symbols to take mean, it becomes biased and again results errors. For example, this normalization resulted 1.8% symbol error rate for 30 symbols received but 30% symbol error rate for 3 symbols received.

Keen observation. That's one of the reasons that whitening your signal is crucial! And why 30 symbols might be much too short a sequence to calculate a reasonably reliable average on. (Notice how for AWGN you can infer your estimator's variance directly from the noise variance.)

> `rx_symbols = rx_symbols ./ mean(abs(rx_symbols));`

Yeah, but that only works for a stationary, flat channel. The fact that your `H` is a capital letter indicates your channel is not flat, but a matrix to applied to your symbol vector: I guess this is something like an OFDM system, which you forgot to mention.

(also, your code formatting is really bad; felt compelled to fix it in my answer. Spaces come around operators, and only after commas, and not before closing parentheses, if you want to be consistent. Matlab code is bad enough to read due to the language – try to be tidy about it!)

In real-world systems, 64-QAM transmission *typically* (not: exclusively) happen on relatively wide channels, so that you need some means of equalization anyways. So, either you send a longer known preamble, of which you know the power exactly, or you're continuously updating your attenuation estimate as you go along – for example through *decision-feedback equalization*, where the result of your decision is fed back to adjust the correction factor, or by feed-forward methods like FF AGCs (not as popular on varying-envelope constellations like QAM).

Comment: Yes it's an OFDM system, to be more precisize, its cell-free massive mimo system. I tried and failed to do demodulation without equalization. Thank you for your answer, I'll focus on equalization techniques more.

Comment: you do OFDM *because* you need equalization, that's the whole point of doing OFDM, which comes at a high cost, as you waste time for guard intervals (typically, even transmit energy, as you put your cyclic prefix in that). Remember the basics of your system before doing cool advanced stuff :)